# Как считывать из строки двузначное число? Строковый калькулятор. Постфиксный вид

Tags: c++, c, алгоритм, c++11, c++14

Проблема в строковом калькуляторе, я считываю числа из строки посимвольно и записываю их в массив, НО когда в строке встречается двузначное число, оно естественно записывается с разными индексами, а не одним числом.

*Что в коде происходит?*
Читает строку и преобразовывает выражение в постфиксный вид, затем выполняется вычисление

```
    int prior (char s)
{
    int a = 0;
    switch (s) {
        case '*':
            a = 3;
            break;
        case '/':
            a = 3;
            break;
        case '-':
            a = 2;
            break;
        case '+':
            a = 2;
            break;
        case '(':
            a = 1;
            break;
    }
    return a;
}

void st_machine (string text) {
    stack<char> st;
    stack<int>val_stack;
    string a;
    int outputi = 0;
    char outstr[20];
    int point = 0, n1=0, n2=0, res;
    int p = 0;
    while (p < text.length())
    {
        char curr = text.at(p);

        if (isdigit(curr)){
            outstr[point++] = curr;
        }

        if (curr == '+' || curr == '-' || curr == '/' || curr == '*'){
            if (st.empty()){
                st.push(curr);
            }
            else {
                if (prior(st.top()) < prior(curr)){
                    st.push(curr);
                }
                else {
                    while (prior(st.top()) >= prior(curr)){
                        outstr[point++] = st.top(); st.pop();
                    }
                    st.push(curr);
                }
            }
        }

        if (curr == '('){
            st.push(curr);
        }

        if (curr == ')'){
            while (st.top() != '('){
                outstr[point++] = st.top(); st.pop();
                }
            if (st.top() == '('){
                st.pop();
            }
        }
        p++;
    }
    while (st.empty() != true) {
        outstr[point++] = st.top(); st.pop();
    }

    //a = outstr;
    point = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i<strlen(outstr); i++){
        //cout<<outstr[i];
        if (isdigit(outstr[i])){
            val_stack.push((int)outstr[i]-48);
        }
        else
        {
            n2 = val_stack.top(); val_stack.pop();
            n1 = val_stack.top(); val_stack.pop();

            switch (outstr[i]){
                case '+': res = n1+n2; break;
                case '-': res = n1-n2; break;
                case '*': res = n1*n2; break;
                case '/': res = n1/n2; break;
            }
            val_stack.push(res);
        }
    }
    outputi = val_stack.top();

    cout<<"output: " << outputi << "\n";
}
```

В text я передаю строку string f = "(8+(6/2+10)*(3+1))/2";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение, если кому потребуется.

```
#include <stack>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int prior (char s)
{
    int a = 0;
    switch (s) {
        case '*':
            a = 3;
            break;
        case '/':
            a = 3;
            break;
        case '-':
            a = 2;
            break;
        case '+':
            a = 2;
            break;
        case '(':
            a = 1;
            break;
    }
    return a;
}

void st_machine (string text) {
    stack<char> st;
    stack<int> val_stack;
    //string a;
    string tmp = "", numbers = "";
    int count = 0, pp = 0, temp = 0, outputi = 0,
        point = 0, n1=0, n2=0, res,
        p = 0, i = 0;

    p = 0;
        while (p < text.length()){
            tmp = "";
            while (isdigit(text[p]))
            {
                tmp += text[p];
                count++;
                p++;
            }
            if (count > 0)
            {
                numbers += tmp;
                numbers += " ";
                p += count;
                temp = count;
                count = 0;
                p -= temp;
            }

        if (text[p] == '+' || text[p] == '-' || text[p] == '/' || text[p] == '*'){
            if (st.empty()){
                st.push(text[p]);
            }
            else {
                if (prior(st.top()) < prior(text[p])){
                    st.push(text[p]);
                }
                else {
                    while (prior(st.top()) >= prior(text[p])){
                        numbers += st.top(); st.pop(); numbers += " ";
                    }
                    st.push(text[p]);
                }
            }
        }

        if ( text[p] == '('){
            st.push( text[p]);
        }

        if ( text[p] == ')'){
            while (st.top() != '('){
                numbers += st.top(); st.pop(); numbers += " ";
                }
            if (st.top() == '('){
                st.pop();
            }
        }
        p++;
    }

    while (st.empty() != true) {
        numbers += st.top(); st.pop(); numbers += " ";
    }

//
    for (i = 0; i<numbers.length(); i++){
        tmp = "";
        pp = i;
        point = 0;
        while (numbers[pp] != ' '){
            tmp += numbers[pp];
            pp++;
            point++;
        }
        switch (point){
            case 2: i+=1; break;
            case 3: i+=2; break;
            case 4: i+=3; break;
        }

        if (isdigit(tmp[0])){
            val_stack.push(atoi(tmp.c_str()));
        }
        else if (tmp[0] == '/' || tmp[0] == '+' || tmp[0] == '-' || tmp[0] == '*')
        {
            n2 = val_stack.top(); val_stack.pop();
            n1 = val_stack.top(); val_stack.pop();

            switch (numbers[i]){
                case '+': res = n1+n2; break;
                case '-': res = n1-n2; break;
                case '*': res = n1*n2; break;
                case '/': res = n1/n2; break;
            }
            val_stack.push(res);
        }
    }
    outputi = val_stack.top();

    cout<< outputi << "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Объединяйте цифры в число (если я не ошибся в порядке цифр):

```
if (isdigit(outstr[i])){
     int t = (int)outstr[i]-48;
     while (isdigit(outstr[++i])
           t = t * 10 + (int)outstr[i]-48;
     val_stack.push(t);
```

А в целом  - outstr фактически играет роль дублирующего стека - так лучше завести один стек вместо outstr и val_stack, в который складывать структуры, содержащие или число, или операцию, и признак - число это или операция. Числа формировать по тому принципу, что я написал, только брать данные из входной строки

Comment: outstr = 862/10+31+*+2/

если объединять числа, то в стек кладется число 862, а нужно, чтобы было раздельно, а 10 вместе

те нужно так чтобы в outstr '10' лежало в одном индексе, а сейчас получается
[4] = 1
[5] = 0

Comment: `while (p < text.length())
    {
        char curr = text.at(p);
        
        if (isdigit(curr)){
            outstr[point++] = curr;
        }
`

нужно как то считывать строку не посимвольно, а число целиком, возможно преобразовать входную строку в строку с пробелами и как то это использовать